# APINotAllowedError while posting via Instagram API

Tags: ios, api, instagram

There seems to be a bug in Instagram API. When I post a request to like a media, I get following response.

```
{
  "meta":  {
    "error_type": "APINotAllowedError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "you cannot like this media"
  }
}
```

My code was working fine previously. But now it does not work. I've also tested the LIKE api on Instagram website's API Console. The API Console on Instagram website also returns the same output. Can someone please look into the issue help me.

Here is the sample request that I send through API Console on Instagram website.

```
POST /v1/media/742359403607622196/likes?access_token=1141855090.1fb234f.1073806ddd2c46d2bbfb3259b1a5ef1c HTTP/1.1
X-HostCommonName: api.instagram.com
Host: api.instagram.com
Content-Length: 0
X-Target-URI: https://api.instagram.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using another Instagram account for your application.

I got the same issue with the '400' error. I would assume there is an undocumented limit for calls per second or minute, because I started getting '400' error after trying to multithread likes posting.

But in my case the same function works perfectly with access_token from another account (I just made less threads and added some delay for my func).

Comment: I've tried using another Instagram Account. But the same thing happens. I think there is some issue on Instagram API. I've seen the same behavior on some other apps on AppStore too. I cant like media even after waiting for 5-6 hours.

Comment: Is any of you got solution on above issue ?

Comment: try using another instagram app id and other app id from other users account but the error is same.

Answer (score 0):

When you authorise your app with the user to you request like and commenting permissions. When you make the initial redirect to the instagram site to get the code you need a `scope` parameter for certain permissions, e.g `&scope=likes+relationships`